# How can I detect a nested object with jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, object, datatables, twig

This is my json file:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Cat","productgroup":[{"id":5,"name":"Animals"},{"id":6,"name":"Female"}]},{"id":2,"name":"Dog","productgroup":[{"id":5,"name":"Animals"},{"id":7,"name":"Male"}]},
```

This is how I load data into my datatables (using twig):

```
 "columns": [
     {% for key, value in columns %}
     {   "data": "{{ key }}"},
     {% endfor %}
  ]
```

So this is actually replacing this:

```
 "columns": [
     {"data": "id"},
     {"data": "name"},
     {"data": "productgroup"},
  ]
```

But because "productgroup" is a nested object I would need this:

```
 "columns": [
     {"data": "id"},
     {"data": "name"},
     {"data": "productgroup[, ].name"},
  ]
```

I actually have a working solution for a nested object, when it is does not have multiple values, just for single:

```
 [{"id":3,"name":"Leaf","icon":{"id":4,"name":"leaf"}],
```

The output here needs to be:

```
 "columns": [
         {"data": "id"},
         {"data": "name"},
         {"data": "icon.name"},
      ]
```

It works very well with this solution:

```
"columnDefs": [
      {
        "render": function (data, type, row) {
          var type = typeof data;
          if(type == "object"){
            return data.name;
          } else {
            return data ;
          }
        },
```

So what I would need is something like this:

```
"columnDefs": [
          {
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
              var type = typeof data;
              if(type == "object"){
                  if(object is nested){
                  return data[, ].name;
                  } else {
                  return data.name;
                  }
              } else {
                return data ;
              }
            },
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values maybe?

Comment: or even https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames

Comment: @Alex This is returning `[object Array Iterator]` not the value

Comment: This: `return data[0].name;` is actually returning the value `Animals`. But not `Animals, Female`

Comment: I just need to replace this: `{"data": "productgroup[, ].name"},`

Comment: is productgroup always an array?

Comment: your wanted output also makes no sense really. can you please make an example of the actual output/ array/ object you wish for with real values? like do you want "icon.name" or the actual name value inside icon? i believe you might want to look at array map

Comment: the name is not always `productgroup`, sometimes it is something else. I just need to detect the difference between this `"key":{"key":value,"key":"value"}` and this `"key":[{"key":value,"key":"value"}]`

Comment: @Alex It makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just need to detect the difference between this "key":{"key":value,"key":"value"} and this "key":[{"key":value,"key":"value"}]

You can simply check if a value is an array using:

```
Array.isArray(myobject.mykey)
```

This returns false for `foo` in `{ foo: { lorem: "ipsum", dolor: "sit" } }` and returns true for `foo` in `{ foo: [{ lorem: "ipsum", dolor: "sit" }] }`

Comment: Thank you. This is my approach to use your code in my columnDefs:   `"render": function (data, type, row) { if(Array.isArray(data.name)){
              return data[, ].name;
            }else {
              return data.name;
            }}`

Comment: Something is still wrong, but if I figure out how to write this line correctly, everything is fine

Comment: I have to write `if(Array.isArray(data)` I think then this part is correct. But this one is still making problems: `data[, ].name;`

Comment: you said its not always called `productgroup` so i dont know what to check inside `isArray()`. also, i have never seen `[, ].keyname` what is that supposed to do? is this es6 syntax?

Comment: Maybe you did never work with datatables. That's why it sounds strange to you. If I write in ColumnDefs `return data` then I get in Columns `{"data": "whatever"},`. If I write in ColumnDefs `return data.name` then I get in Columns `{"data": "whatever.name"},`. What I actually need in Columns is `{"data": "whatever[, ].name"},`. So in ColumnDefs I try to write `return data[, ].name` but this is not working

Comment: I tried also to write `return data + "[, ]"+ .name` but this did not work either

Comment: yes, i literally have no clue about that :) maybe you need `data + "[, ].name"` but neither do i know what data is nor if you need `".name"` as literal string or replaced with a variable. thats what i meant by your question is a bit confusing/ not clear

Comment: `data + "[, ].name"` This unfortunately did not work out. But thank you, you actually solved what was my main problem. This is just little thing, I am going to make a new question for that

Comment: was working with this `return data.map(obj => obj.name);` :)

Comment: @Jarla glad i could help :)